# randomGaussian() in Processing 3

Tags: java, processing, distribution, normal-distribution

thanks for opening this question.

I just learned how to use `randomGaussian()` in **Processing 3**.
According to the doc,  this function

> Returns a float from a random series of numbers having a mean of 0 and standard deviation of 1.

and I created a movement like this

```
if (x < mouseX){
    x+= randomGaussian();
  } else {
    x-= randomGaussian();
  }
```

> Post-answered-supplementary-notes:
>   x is an integer;

```
int x;
```

other related code is only about draw...

```
ellipse(x,height/2,8,8);
```

yeah, I want to make the object move towards the mouse's direction,
but it turns out

The movement of the object would always be negative (move to the left no matter where is the mouse.

If I wrote

```
    x+= randomGaussian()+1;
```

It would work properly.My personal understanding of this function is it returns approximately a mathematical set of [-1,1] (and majority cluster around the mean value 0).

But it seems my understanding is wrong.

I wonder why the original code doesn't work as I thought... (after I typed this sentence down I realized this must be an universe question.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: So what’s your question?

Comment: I wonder why randomGaussian() wouldn't return a value to make the increment! (added in the post, I know this's confusing :^(

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: What is `x`? Is it an `int`?

Comment: You have a mistaken concept of Gaussians.  They are a continuous (i.e., floating point for computing) symmetric distribution of numbers on the range [-infinity +infinity].  A standard Gaussian is centered at zero and a bit more than 95% of the outcomes fall in the range [-2, 2], equally likely to be positive or negative, with the highest concentration around zero.

Comment: yeah.. have to admit my math is pretty weak and I have been lack of practice for a long time. when the programming task gets involved with math I just messed up more terrible, I should review math definition to make sure I understand it solidly first. Thanks for pointing out the concept mistake for me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you're storing `x` as an `int` value. Remember that `int` values can only hold whole numbers like `1`, `50`, `200`, etc. They can't hold decimals like `1.5` or `3.14`.

So when you have an `int` value like `50` and add a decimal like `0.5` to it, the `50.5` value is **truncated** and becomes `50` again. In other words it doesn't change. But if you have `50` and subtract `0.5` from it, it becomes `49.5`, which is truncated to `49`. This is why you only ever see the value decrease.

To get around this problem, simply declare your `x` value as a `float` so it can hold decimal values.

Also note that this doesn't make sense:

```
if (x < mouseX){
  x+= randomGaussian();
} else {
  x-= randomGaussian();
}
```

The `randomGaussian()` function returns a value between `-1` and `1`. It makes no difference whether you add or subtract it, because it's going to be negative about 50% of the time.

Instead, you either need to shift the value returned by, say, adding `2` to it, or you can just use the regular `random()` function which takes parameters for the range you want your value to be in. More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/random_.html).

Comment: Thanks!!! (I'm sorry I've been snoozed for a while and didn't check the message. The second para of your answer got my question. (so sorry about missing tons of important details, while this reminds me why I made this kind of issue//the ignorance of some basics...(the fact is I was working on an exer that requires defining the step size of a random walker using the normal distribution. But yes, it's not the correct way to use it like this I think.) Thanks for answering my question! X^)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your question is or what you're trying to do, but the answer might very well be:

`x += Math.abs( randomGaussian() );` 
or 
`x -= Math.abs( randomGaussian() );`

I think you actually want to control the direction and because your set is -1 to 1 probably isn't as useful for you (adding one to this would make it appear to work as it would be 0-2).

Secondly, MouseX/Y are ints if I remember correctly (isn't Processing integer coordinates by default?), you just might not be moving them enough for it to make a difference so by adding one you're suddenly affecting it enough.

My suggestion is to use the gaussian as a scalar on whatever you're drawing so you can see what's going on. Something more like:

```
float scalar = Math.abs( randomGaussian() ); //0 -> 100% leaning towards 0
float amount = 10f; //10 pixels or whatever
if(moveLeft) {
  x += amount * scalar;
} else {
  x -= amount * scalar;
}
```

(I would definitely refine your question to help other people if this is somehow useful. I like to see Processing questions so I'm happy to help--but the more exact your question the better your response is going to be on a site like this :P)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I appreciate it. I think I understand what you mean by a scalar like I have seen in some tutorials that set a separate mean and deviate value.

Comment: (I was working on an exer that said to define the step size of a random walker, but yes, I missed a lot of details which are vital to answering this problem, anyway, thanks for the help! X^)